# Extend base class with same Name and Namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

This may sound crazy, but:

Can I extend a Class by adding another method, but keep the Class-Name the same?
Also I need to put it into the same Namespace !!

like:

```
class BaseClass {
    BaseMethod() {....}
}

class BaseClass : BaseClass {
    XtendedMethod() {...}
}
```

I am using a Custom Dll with some Action-Methods in an MVC4 application.

This Dll calls the following Controller / Action:

Items/Search

Due to Route-Constraints set up by this dll, I cannot use another Controller-Name.

I need to extend Search-Action but have to keep the Controller-part in the Route.

I want to call:

Items/XtendedSearch

Comment: Why can't you add the method to the same class definition?  Alternatively, look at [Partial Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I think this will only work, if the original class is also "partial" ?? - I cannot change the original code

Comment: Yes, all "parts" of a partial class must be marked partial.  I'm having a hard time following why you have access to the namespace and can add classes, but cannot modify the existing class.  If you need to extend the class with new functionality that does not apply to the entire  base class, it should *not be* the same class, but a child class that inherits from that base class.

Comment: the base classes are in a 3rd-party dll, which I want to extend but cannot simply derive, because the routing values are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

No but you could add an Extension method to solve this

Comment: In theory you're right, that does what OP literally asks, but please provide a link that says ASP.NET MVC also works with extension methods accepting a `Controller` as first parameter, as opposed to adding the appropriate action method to a `Controller` class as I think that is not possible.